# Javascript challenge 1 codedamn

Tags: javascript

```js
const a = 12
const b = 13
[a, b].forEach((el) => console.log(el))
```

can you try to find bug in this?

If I use semicolon after every const it works but I am not able to understand the reason behind it.

The error that I get is b being used before initialization

Comment: Javascript thinks that this is what you want `const b= 13[a,b]`

Comment: It's because Javascript has rules when it comes to where it automatically adds semicolons. Since I have used other languages that require a line terminator I have gotten into the habit of just adding semi colons at the end of my lines in Javascript even though they aren't always required there. I also use a JS compressor so the semi colons stop potential problems there too.